# How do I add a solution to TFS without the local workspace mappings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I just set up a new TFS install for our dev team and I'm trying to put a solution (web site) into TFS.

This site isnt saved as a solution currently so First I do file > open website, then in solution explorer I right click the solution and use the add to TFS option.

When I do this I have 2 problems

1. Sometimes I end up with a new workspace mapping to my C:\ location
   not my TFS workspace folder
2. Every time I do this when the solution
   opens it is pointing to the C:\ folder and not the folder I want it
   to within my TFS workspace folder.

Is there a better way to do this? Im quite new to using TFS in this manner and I have never worked with websites in TFS before so im a bit unsure about what im doing.

Thanks

Comment: You can go to File -> Source Control -> Workspaces to edit the mapping.